# Multiple Where clause in Android SQL statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, where-clause

I am having some problem with the SQL statement for Android. Basically I have two where clause, bookID and userID and the SQL statement that I am having now:

```
public boolean updateLoan(String bookID, String userID, String currentDate) {
    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("loanDate", currentDate);

        mDb.update("loanBook", cv,
                " bookID= '" + bookID + "'", null);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

So I wonder how could I put two where clause in this method as currently I only can where clause by bookID. Do I simply put an "&" and continue the SQL statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I simply put an "&" and continue the SQL statement?

Yes, use AND instead of &

Comment: Opps sorry, my careless mistake. Thanks a lot!